# How can I insert each row of a matrix into cells in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell

Suppose A = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
I want to convert it to B = [{[1,2,3]};{[4,5,6]};{[7,8,9]}]
How can I do that in an easy way?

Comment: try  `num2cell( [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9], 2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) function.

From the documentation:

> C = mat2cell(A,dim1Dist,...,dimNDist) divides array A into smaller
>   arrays within cell array C. Vectors dim1Dist,...dimNDist specify how
>   to divide the rows, columns, and (when applicable) higher dimensions
>   of A.

[image: mat2cell]

You can do it like this:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
B = mat2cell(A, [1 1 1], 3);
```

will give you:

```
B={[1 2 3];[4 5 6];[7 8 9]}
```

---

Documentation also says:

> C = mat2cell(A,rowDist) divides array A into an n-by-1 cell array C,
>   where n == numel(rowDist).

So, if you are always going to split your matrix to rows, but not to columns, you can do it without the second parameter.

```
B = mat2cell(A, [1 1 1]);
```

---

A better, generalized way would be:

```
mat2cell(A, ones(1, size(A, 1)), size(A, 2));
```

Comment: (+1) for a cleaner solution than mine... I know the `mat2cell` and its reverse `cell2mat` functions, but find that I always need the documentation to get them right. On a simple problem like the above, "quick and dirty" beats "clean, elegant, and slow" (because of the lookup in docs...)

Comment: @Floris yes, quick and dirty is good if your matrix is 3x3, but if you are going for bigger datasets it is preferable to go for vectorized solutions.

Comment: Completely agree @HebeleHododo - that is why I upvoted your solution. But I answered the question as it was asked... I am glad to see your answer has now been accepted as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a "matrix of cells" like your notation for B implied.
A cell array allows you to store "any data type" in the individual cells. You can't store a cell as a data type in an array.

So let's assume you meant to say you wanted `B = {[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]};`

If that is the case, then

```
B = cell(1,3);
for ii=1:3
  B(ii) = {A(ii, :)};
end
```

should do the trick.

Note - edited based on Hadi's comment.

Comment: Thanks, both B = [{[1,2,3]};{[4,5,6]};{[7,8,9]}] and B = {[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]} have the same result but the latter is better show.

Comment: conversion from double to cell is needed. A(ii, :) must be inside braces like this: B(ii) = {A(ii, :)};