# Converting dimension of array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell, video-processing

As with my previous question:

> I am using this function I got from the internet:
>
> ```
> >>[Y,U,V]=yuv_import('test.yuv',[176 144],150,0)
> ```
>
> I got this from: [Convert YUV CIF 4:2:0 video file to image files][1]
>
> It prints out the Y, U and V components of the yuv file test.yuv. When
>   I typed:
>
> ```
> >>Y
> ```
>
> It displayed:
>
> ```
> Y = 
>
>   Columns 1 through 5
>
>     [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]
>
> ............... 
>
>   Columns 146 through 150
>
>     [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]
> ```
>
> And..
>
> ```
> >>size(Y)
> ```
>
> displayed:
>
> ```
> ans =
>
>      1   150
> ```
>
> Doing the same for U and V components also showed the same results.
>
> And also..
>
> ```
> >>Y(150)
> ```
>
> displayed:
>
> ```
> ans = 
>
>     [144x176 double]
> ```
>
> What I want is make an array for Y, U and V that has the dimensions
>   [numberOfFrames height width] or [150 144 176]. How can I do this?
>
> [1]: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6318

I got the solution by using

```
>>Y = cat(3, Y{:} );
```

and I have a

```
>>size(Y1)

ans =
```

144   176   150

Now, what I want is to convert it back to its original dimensions. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I insert each row of a matrix into cells in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647056/how-can-i-insert-each-row-of-a-matrix-into-cells-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

Use `mat2cell`

```
>> Y = mat2cell( Y1, size(Y1,1), size(Y1,2), ones(1,size(Y1,3)) );
```